# Flask-RESTful with Firebase randomly returns Null

Tags: python, firebase, flask, flask-restful

TL;DR: I'm trying to write a simple read-only API. However, I'm getting a null response from Firebase or from Flask RESTful framework.

```
null
```

I'm trying to fetch data from my Firebase Firestore collection. It works well and since it's a simple read-only API, I wanted to use the FlaskRESTful framework. However, when I send multiple requests rapidly, I get "null" as the response.

This doesn't happen when I restart Flask. The first response is always what I want to get from the requested endpoint. However, if I refresh or send the request again, I get a "null" response.

```
class Users(Resource):
    def get(self):
        users = { doc.id: doc.to_dict() for doc in docs }
        return users, 200

api.add_resource(Users, "/user")
```

My question is this: Am I missing something related to Flask? Like, should I close() something? Since I'm not very experienced in Flask, I can't even ask the right question. I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I understand why I had this issue. In my code, I was running the firebase initializer code each time I was requesting an endpoint. Thus, firebase was trying to initialize a new app each time.